# How to define the chatset of a certain dom appended to any webpage with different chatset by jquery(or js)

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, character-encoding

I am doing a chrome extension which may append a button to any web pages using `chrome extension`, `contentscript`. The problem is the charset of the web pages are uncertain, which means that I may append my node to the web pages with different charset. Sometimes it may come with messy code.

Here's the example:

**content_script.js:**

```
(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute('src', 'url_to_my_javascript')
    document.body.appendChild(script)
})()
```

**my_javascript.js:**

```
$('body').append('<button>确定(chinese,means ok)</button>')
```

That comes with messy code on some pages with 'gbk' charset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
script.charset="GBK";//or other charset
```